# Output voltage for clipper circuit with bias

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, biasing

I've been working with diodes recently and I'm struggling understanding how to actually handle them in circuit. In general, I know that they only can pass the current in one direction because of how they're constructed on the inside so to speak.

I'll present to you a problem which I'm working on, and my main thought process. I hope you can find what goes wrong in my reasoning and correct me, so that I can start solving more advanced problems.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCkkqP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**The main problem is to sketch the voltage of the output.** Here comes my reasoning:

We have an AC power supply \$U_{in}\$ with some frequency \$\omega\$ to the left. At first, if we assume that \$U_{in} > 0\$, then the diode will be forward biased. Since we work with ideal diodes, there will not be a voltage drop over the diode. However, because of KVL, we would therefore expect that the output voltage measured between the two nodes on the RHS of the circuit, supposing positive is the node furthest up, to be \$-E\$.

I'm pretty sure I'm thinking correctly here. Now the problem becomes when the input signal switches direction. So obviously, now we'll have to move against the diode. I want to split it up in two cases, namely for when the input voltage is between \$0\$ and \$-E\$, and then when the input voltage is smaller then \$-E\$.

In the first named case, there'll not be any current passing through the power source \$E\$. And in the latter, current will be able to pass through the power source \$E\$, but will be limited by the diode. So the current will not be able to complete itself? What will the output voltage be measured as in those cases? If we see the diode as a short circuit for the current going in the opposite direction, I'm thinking that the output voltage must be \$-E\$ in the first case and \$U_{in}\$ in the latter. But I'm still "guessing" and not really using any logic. If there's anyone who could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you notice that any voltage larger (more positive ) than -E  will make a diode to conduct current?  For example, if E = 1V the diode will be ON if Vin > -1V. So to cut off the diode Vin needs to be more negative than -1V.  https://tinyurl.com/2ldqv3vh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm still "guessing" and not really using any logic.

You did get the correct result. Let me make some suggestions.

1. Labeled Diagrams

Make them a habit. They go a long way to eliminate guessing.

When talking about nodes and currents, having names for them greatly reduces confusion in a discussion and also during analysis. You can see in the diagram below the lowercase letters that I use to name the nodes. Node d has the ground reference symbol attached so that the "d" designation is not really necessary. I can now use to indicate voltages, \$V_{\text{bc}}\$ to indicate the voltage across the diode. This is called double-subscript notation. \$V_{\text{b}}\$ is single-subscript notation that indicates the voltage from node b to the ground reference.

The black arrow indicates the direction for which current is considered positive. The label \$I\$ next to the arrow is the name of the current.

Furthermore we can conclude (although it should be stated explicitly) that the output voltage is the voltage \$V_{\text{b}}\$ at node b.

> the output voltage measured between the two nodes on the RHS of the circuit, supposing positive is the node furthest up, to be −E.

This is very hard to interpret even with a diagram available. Node labeling clarifies.

2. > At first, if we assume that Uin>0, then the diode will be forward biased.

The truth is if \$V_{\text{bc}}>0\$, then the diode will be forward biased. I think you were starting with finding the boundary where the diode begins conduction. To do that apply KVL with \$I=0\$ and \$V_{\text{D}}=0\$. This will reveal that under these constraints:
$$U_{\text{in}}=-E$$

You went on to correctly conclude that while current passed through the diode the output would be \$V_{\text {b}}=-E\$.

3. > I want to split it up in two cases, namely for when the input voltage is between 0 and −E, and then when the input voltage is smaller then −E.

You are still under the illusion that the diode turns on when the input voltage is greater than zero. It was revealed in 2. that the input had to be greater than  \$-E\$ only. There are only two cases: 1) \$I=0\$ and 2} \$I\ne 0\$.

We have the second case from 2), so for the first case, apply KVL again but this time with \$I=0\$ and \$V_{\text{D}}\ne 0\$.

You went on to correctly conclude that while current is zero through the diode the output would be \$V_{\text {b}}=U_{\text{in}}\$.

To write the result in a clear way, try the following:
The output voltage is
$$V_{b}=\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
U_{in},U_{in}<-E\\
-E,U_{in}\geq-E
\end{array}\right.$$

Hope this helps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f30AOA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This really made it clear for me. As you pointed out, I always believed that as soon as the voltage source was greater than 0, the diode was on. Therefore I should always just check the voltage over the diode to see whether it'll be forward biased or not. Thanks, this cleared alot of my confusion.